# How to wrap every 3 div's contents in a div?

Tags: html, wordpress, loops

I need every three divs of class "loopcontent" to be wrapped in a new div of class "threeacross". I'm new to WordPress and really not a PHP guy yet, but I'm learning as I go.

Here's my loop:

```
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="loopcontent">
                <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } else {
                        // the current post lacks a thumbnail
                    }
                ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>

            <div class="loopcontent">
                <h1>Page Not Found</h1> 
                <p>Looks like the page you're looking for isn't here anymore. Try browsing the <a href="">categories</a>, <a href="">archives</a>, or using the search box below.</p>
                <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/searhform.php'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap it with jQuery? Why can't you do it within the loop itself?

Comment: I'm brand new to wordpress after many years of MovableType and I'm kind of clueless about php, but I'm learning as I go...  so...  if you know a way to accomplish that, please let me know.  I'd definitely prefer that!  I'm trying to wrap every third "loopcontent" div inside a "threeacross" div.

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery for this purpose. Post everything from the line that contains "while(have_posts())" to the line that says "endwhile;" on the template in question. What you want can be easily achieved on the server-side.

Comment: OK!  I edited my question and posted the wordpress code instead.

Comment: Do you want every 3rd post to be wrapped in, or every 3rd displayed post to be wrapped. There is a huge difference.

Comment: I have each post wrapped in a div on my index page, so it's essentially the same thing, is it not?  Loopcontent is one piece of looped content (one post, in other words) wrapped in a div.  I need every grouping of three of those divs, wrapped in an outer div.  I'm basically creating a table of three post excerpts across by how ever many rows worth of posts I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work. This keeps a running count and places your div wraps every three posts. Let me know if this helps. If not, let me know what it's outputting, and I can tweak it:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : for($count=0;have_posts();$count++) : the_post();
    $open = !($count%3) ? '<div class="threeacross">' : ''; //Create open wrapper if count is divisible by 3
    $close = !($count%3) && $count ? '</div>' : ''; //Close the previous wrapper if count is divisible by 3 and greater than 0
    echo $close.$open;
?>
<div class="loopcontent">
    <?php
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail();
    else{
    // the current post lacks a thumbnail
    }
    ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endfor; else : ?>
<div class="loopcontent">
    <h1>Page Not Found</h1> 
    <p>Looks like the page you're looking for isn't here anymore. Try browsing the <a href="">categories</a>, <a href="">archives</a>, or using the search box below.</p>
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/searhform.php'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $count ? '</div>' : ''; //Close the last wrapper if post count is greater than 0 ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'
here:
`$close = !($count%3) && $count ? '</div>';`

Comment: I think that's working.  I'll have to style the threeaccross and see what I get.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much for this. It worked perfectly for me as well. I wish I could give you more than 1 upvote!

Comment: I know this answer is a bit old but i must vote up and thank, i have been searching for 3 hours how to do this to implement twitter bootstrap on my theme and this is perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: This helped thanks. It confused me a couple of times because you're using the fact that boolean logic results in `0` and `1` with PHP. I have explicitly tested against the number in my usage so I don't get confused coming back in a few months time.

Comment: @rtpHarry Correct. I have a personal tendency to rely on PHP's internal evaluation of "truthy" and "falsy" values in ternary operators, which can sometimes create readability issues for others. Strict checks are a much better way of handling this in the long-term, so by all means, use it where you can!